# Sniffing Application Network Traffic on Windows

Tags: windows-7, vpn, sniffing

I have an application running on my computer which communicates with a server over Windows-VPN. I would like to sniff the traffic between that app and the server but Wireshark f.x. will only show me the already encrypted traffic.

Is there a way to accomplish that on Windows 7?

Comment: Is it HTTP traffic?  If so look at [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: well - that actually does the trick, man - care to turn it into an answer? maybe adding some of your sniffing-wisdom for goodies?